# Is it possible to include PolarSSL and OpenSSL in the same project?

Tags: openssl, ld, mbedtls, polarssl

I have a software which include paho.mqtt.c with openSSL.

I want to include libcurl in it, which was built with polarSSL(newly mbedTLS).

When I include polarSSL to the project, i get a lot of Name clash:

```
build/MQTTAsync.o: In function `memory_set_own':
usr/include/polarssl/memory.h:55: multiple definition of `memory_set_own'
usr/include/polarssl/memory.h:55: first defined here
```

Is it possible to include both library and if it is, what is my mistake ?

If it isn't possible, I guess I should try to build cURL with polarSSL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should not use PolarSSL at all! It is not maintained anymore, and only MbedTLS is maintained.

And I should know, because I used to be the core maintainer of PolarSSL!

Regarding your error, it seems the same header is included multiple times, which is causing you issues.